# find directories containing multiple file sharing the same basename

Tags: find

How would I modify the following bash instruction to get only the directories that match exactly `genre_` (basename) and another `genre_*`. As the next step, I appended `| wc -l` to the second `find`, but I get for each line the same very high number, which tells me it's a count across directories (why?)?

```
$ find . -name 'genre_' -exec dirname {} \; | while EFS= read -r thedir; do echo "$(find . -name 'genre_*')"; done
./The-Specials/genre_
./The-Specials/genre_rock
./ACDC/genre_Hard-Rock
./We-3/genre_
./We-3/genre_Jazz
```

In the output above, only ACDC should be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't understand what your code is supposed to do (read: the question is not clear in this matter). However I can answer this:

> As the next step, I appended `| wc -l` to the second `find`, but I get for each line the same very high number, which tells me it's a count across directories (why?)

You `read -r thedir` but `thedir` is never used. The second `find` is the same command every time, starting in `.`, hence the same number.

Bonus: I don't see the point of `echo "$(find …)"`. This code smells fishy. It probably should be just `find …`.

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `$thedir` in place of `.` inside the second `find` statement. This solved it: `$ find . -name 'genre_' -exec dirname {} \; | while EFS= read -r thedir; do var="$(find $thedir -regex '.*genre_.*'| wc -l)"; if (( "$var" > 1 )); then rm "$thedir"/genre_; fi; done
` but I welcome any suggestion to make it more concise.